# compare two diff fields in two files

Tags: unix

I need to compare field1, field5 in fileA to field5, field6 in fileB
and print out when there are no matches:

```
file A
ZEROC_ZAR,MKT,M,ZAR,3YEAR,7.59
ZEROC_AED,MKT,M,ZAR,4YEAR,7.84
ZEROC_ZAR,MKT,M,ZAR,5YEAR,8.03
ZEROC_AED,MKT,M,ZAR,7YEAR,8.33


file B
TKS,010690226,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,3YEAR
TKS,010690231,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,4YEAR
TKS,010690233,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,5YEAR
TKS,010690235,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,7YEAR
TKS,010690236,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,10YEAR
```

Comment: So what's the expected output? And what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

This oneliner prints the non-matching lines of fileB:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,5 fileA | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} fileB | cat - fileB | sort | uniq -u
TKS,010690226,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,3YEAR
TKS,010690233,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,5YEAR
TKS,010690236,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,10YEAR
```

Explanation:

First combine fields 1 and 5 of fileA:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,5 fileA
ZEROC_ZAR,3YEAR
ZEROC_AED,4YEAR
ZEROC_ZAR,5YEAR
ZEROC_AED,7YEAR
```

Use these strings to grep for matching lines in fileB:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,5 fileA | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} fileB
TKS,010690231,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,4YEAR
TKS,010690235,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,7YEAR
```

Then use `cat - fileB | sort` to combine these two lines with the content of fileB:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,5 fileA | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} fileB | cat - fileB | sort
TKS,010690226,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,3YEAR
TKS,010690231,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,4YEAR
TKS,010690231,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,4YEAR
TKS,010690233,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,5YEAR
TKS,010690235,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,7YEAR
TKS,010690235,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,7YEAR
TKS,010690236,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,10YEAR
```

Finally, use `uniq -u` to remove duplicate lines:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,5 fileA | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} fileB | cat - fileB | sort | uniq -u
TKS,010690226,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,3YEAR
TKS,010690233,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,5YEAR
TKS,010690236,02977,AED,ZEROC_AED,10YEAR
```